# check if number exists in subdocument with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, math, random, mongoose, subdocument

I have a document which looks like:

```
var User = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    name: String,
    position: [{
              _id:ObjectId,
              index_number:Number,
                    preference:[{
                        candidate_id: String,
                        weightedScore:Number,
                        position_id:String,
                        candidate_index_number:Number
                    }],
```

When I add a position, I generate an index_number using `var index_number = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);`

But I need to check if this number exists in the subdocument for any other position before I add it. So i need to check the number, and run the function again if number does exist, until i get a number that doesn't..
But this function doesn't go into the sub document..

```
 User.count({index_number: index_number}, function (err, count){
      if(count>0){
            console.log("no");
      }
      else{
          console.log("okay");
      }
```

how do I loop through the function and check the sub documents for the index_number? or is there a way that I am unaware of that allows me to insert a unique number that isn't an object Id with Mongoose?

Comment: well you can allow only unique numbers to be stored in the field index_number, if you want i can show you how?

Comment: @sacDahal oh yes please that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the field index_number to store only unique value.

```
index_number: {type: Number, index: { unique: true } },
```

So if any duplicacy occurs it will throw an error in your callback which you can catch.